# Kotlin using ArgumentCaptor.capture() returns null

Tags: kotlin, testing, mockito

I'm pretty new to testing so I might be doing something wrong.I'm trying to capture the values that are passed to a method

```
    @Mock
    private lateinit var service: TestService


    @InjectMocks
    private lateinit var underTest: UnderTestService

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
        fun `testMethod`() {
            //given
            val var1 = Test.Value
            val var2 = TestClass::class.java
            val var3 = listOf(Entry1(), Entry2())
    
            //when
            underTest.method(var1, var2, var3)
    
            val argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String::class.java)
    
            verify(service, times(2)).method(
                argumentCaptor.capture(),
                argumentCaptor.capture()

        )
```

Here, after doing verify the argumentCaptor.capture() return null for some reason and I don't understand what am I doing wrong?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: argumentCaptor.capture() must not be null
```

I think that it is kotlin related, the signature of the method that I'm trying to get the parameters looks like this

```
    fun method(param1: String, vararg param2: String?) {
            //do something
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MockitoKotlinHelpers.kt](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSampleKotlin/app/src/test/java/com/example/android/observability/MockitoKotlinHelpers.kt) can help you here. The capture function provides a way to call `ArgumentCaptor.capture()`

Example:

```
verify(service, times(2)).method(
                capture(argumentCaptor),
                capture(argumentCaptor));
```

Comment: Write that helper, same as the above link! And use it.

Answer (score 1):

Using [Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin) (an official Mockito library) can solve this for you.

It adds some syntactic sugar on top of Mockito. For example, a function `whenever` that is basically an alias for `when`, so that you don't need to use `` `when` `` with back-ticks.

It also has a method `argumentCaptor()` which creates an argument captor that does not have the `NullPointerException` issue. Example usage:

```kotlin
val argumentCaptor = argumentCaptor<String>()

verify(service, times(2)).method(
    argumentCaptor.capture(),
    argumentCaptor.capture(),
)
```